# Adding custom controls in Fabric.js in versions prior to 4.0.0

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

For various reasons, I'm using an old version of fabric.js in my project - `3.0`. I'm able to customize the current controls but would need multiple `mtr`s - one for each corner. Is this possible?